# How to turn on notifications?

Tags: android

I created an android app and set up a push notification which works perfectly in all android devices below marshmallow. I understand that, initially the permission is disabled. I needed some features like camera, I achieved this by prompting required permission. Is there any way like this to on notification. If not how to go to notification permission giving activity programmatically

Thanks in advance

Comment: Notifications are enabled by default - Use `NotificationManagerCompat.areNotificationsEnabled()` method to check if a user has disabled them

Comment: Thanks for answering, in some phones its disabled. So when the app starts for first time i need to check whether it is disabled, if yes prompt it somehow to user to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but with O. Turns out that notifications from O on must be assigned to a Channel.

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels.html